# ANTLR left recursive rule precedence

Tags: antlr4

when attempting to define ANTLR grammars containing left-recursive rules, the precedence of the alternative does sometimes behave unexpectedly.

For example, assuming a (minimal) grammar which should parse a left recursive expression (`E '&&' E`), any other recursive expression (`! E`), and a terminal, such as variables, is used along with an input of `!a && a`.

Given the following grammar:

```
grammar TestGrammar;

start : expr EOF;
expr : notexpr | expr '&&' expr | ID;
notexpr : '!' expr;

ID: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]* ;
```

and an input string of `!a && a`, the resulting parse tree is the equivalent of `!(a && a)`, ignoring the precedence.
I would have expected a result such as `(!a) && (a)` instead.

When substituting the `notexpr` reference within the `expr` rule with the actual not expression
(`expr : '!' expr | expr '&&' expr | ID;`), the parse tree is the expected `(!a) && (a)`.

I am now wondering if I missed a part within the documentation or stumbled upon an ANTLR bug (using version 4.13.1).

Comment: Don't hide operators behind another rule, e.g., `notexpr`. It thwarts implementing operator precedence using Antlr4's ordered-alts feature. `grammar T2; start : expr EOF; expr : '!' expr | expr '&&' expr | ID; ID: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]* ; WS: [ \t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);`

Comment: The extra rule was necessary due to the size of a grammar, resulting in reaching the limit of Java's limit for method size of the resulting parser. (There is the need for the various expressions' rules to be individually present too - and then various derivations of these expressions too) - that's why I was wondering if it is a bug or missing documentation.

Comment: As an addendum: The difference in between both variants appears to be, that the lookahead for parsing the `expr` prod used is different. (hiding it behind the notexpr rule uses no lookahead, while not hiding it uses a lookahead of 3)

Comment: For input `!a&&a` the parse executes `expr()` which switches on `LA(1)` (==`!`), and immediately calls `notexpr()`. At that point, we are now on a different ATN rule, with input `a&&a`. The context now contains a `notexpr` context, and we call `expr()`. Even though we are calling `expr()` from within another `expr()`, it seems that the code doesn't compare operator precedence between `&&` and `!` because of the intervening call to `notexpr`. It seems reasonable that it could be supported, but likely it's not because there might be difficulties in getting it working. So, it's likely not a bug.

Comment: The parameter `_p` of `expr(int _p)` is not lookahead, it is the precedence of the current context. The precedence is purposefully reset in `notexpr()` because it call `expr(0)`. The function is implementing Richard 
 (of BCPL fame) "precedence climbing method".

Comment: Thanks for the replies - And precedence does indeed make more sense. I'm gonna take the time to read upon the theories before even thinking about proposing a PR to possibly support my case.